# What is the reason to put two MOSFETs in a series connection?

Tags: mosfet, repair, troubleshooting

background first:
I am currently trying to repair my old Pioneer amplifier (A-405R). The error description behaviour is a sporadic infinite triggering of the relay (marked blue one in the schematics).
In the working case, V_G = 4.8 V. In the not working case it is below 4 V.

What I am really wondering (due to lack of HW experience): Why are these two MOSFETs (2SK1132: [Datasheet MOSFET](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/202167/NEC/2SK1132/1)) in series? So I thought the benefit of that MOSFET is to switch the relay on and off. Why do you need to then there?

[image: Detailed MOSFET schematic]

EDIT: See here for the more detailed schematic. Complete datasheet of the amplifier can be found under: [Datasheet Amplifier](https://www.manualslib.com/products/Pioneer-A-405r-6918375.html)

[image: Primary Assy / Power Supply]

Comment: It does look odd - the MOSFETs have an in-built gate-source resistor too - another odd-ball thing to have. Are you absolutely positive that GND connects where you show it?

Comment: @Andyaka what "resistor"?  There's some sort of bidirectional breakdown diode thing between gate and source on the data sheet, likely an early form of ESD protection as unprotected gates of early FET's were notorious for ESD damage in handling.

Comment: Look at the first page bullets @ChrisStratton - I don't know if this constitutes an inbuilt resistor but it sounds like one and the circuit would need it.

Comment: One strategy, at least if the surrounding circuitry can be sufficiently understood to validate it, might be to use a single more robust modern logic-level FET...

Comment: @Andyaka "can be replaced with any resistor self-contained type transistor" is a Japanese to English mistranslation of what replaces what, to quote the NEC application guide for these "in applications, such as interfacing small signals, where the MOS FET is used in a low current region, the MOS FET can smoothly replace the existing transistors containing resistors." https://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf/download.php?id=83c151f730808ee89751b1b694969f91876663  The gate protection diode thingy is also mentioned.

Comment: @ChrisStratton without a gate source resistor (or defined gate source leakage or defined diode leakage), the circuit makes no more sense to me.

Comment: I'm not saying it makes sense to me either, however, the FET *does not* have a resistor.  It could be that they think it's okay to actually use the built in breakdown diode thingy routinely not just for pre-assembly ESD (pretty oddly, NEC states the leakage current for the test condition of applying the absolute maximum!) and this somehow works with DB16.

Comment: @Ernte183 please show the surrounding circuitry in particular the actual ground path as Andy asked, specify what the supply voltage to the relay is, and explain what the *function* of the relay in the amplifier is.

Comment: One reason to put two FETs in series is fault tolerance/single point failure mitigation, though I'd be surprised to see that in a consumer level product.  The question to ask would be "if I only have a single FET and it shorts drain to source, what are the consequences."

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I added the schematics of the power supply part of the amplifier in my original thread. Unfortunately, I cannot find the datasheet of the relay and therefore, I do not know how big the supply voltage is supposed to be. The working circuit is directly connected to the 230V AC. Hence, it's function is to power up the complete amplifier (the 230V AC are leading directly to a transformer to the the main board). Does that answer your request in any way?

Comment: What signal is on 'ACRY'

Comment: It looks like this is a little pony power supply to feed a low voltage on-off switch, I'd check that the 5.6 volts is actually DC not AC for some reason of failure.  Unless this is part of a protection circuit too(?) I'd seriously consider just replacing it with some other relay drive FET, or even just bridging the relay contact and giving the product some other power switch, eg, plug it into a power strip with a switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with MOSFET especially in power circuits and noisy environments is 'Single Event Upset' (SEU) that creates a 'Single Event Latch-up' (SEL). The SEU can make a MOSFET to turn on un-intentionally and in the case of SEL, the MOSFET won't turn off anymore until we recycle the power line. The use of two MOSFETs in series makes it possible to lower the probability of these events. If one of the MOSFETs is turned on by an SEL, the other one will prevent the current pass. More info can be found here:

[Wikipedia - Latch-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch-up)